# What is the white material which comes out of steam holes?

Tags: material-identification, tool-usage

When I used the steam feature with my iron, some white material came out right before the steam did. What is that material?

Comment: Someone has used a powder-based cleaner for the base of the iron, for example, bicarb soda? If you are in a hard water area, it might be a deposit, but I have not seen that on my iron. How much material is there? Is it gritty, sticky etc?

Comment: The material was gritty, but it only came out one time.@Stefan

Comment: Reopened as it is about tool usage, upkeep, and maintenance, which is currently on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I live in a hard water area and always get limescale from my iron.  You can buy demineralised ironing water, but I tend to use the condensed water from my dehumidifier or melted frost from the very top of the freezer

Comment: Does anything ever emerge from your iron?

Comment: @Stefan yes, limescale. That's what I meant by "get... from".

Comment: Nothing other than steam. @Stefan

Comment: Bang on answer.  Hard water is the bane of many irons for this reason.